# jQuery Error connection refused

Tags: jquery, ajax, tomcat7, tomcat8

I created a JAVA web application using Apache Tomcat 8, and used jQuery ajax to call a servlet. Then I used the same application using Apache Tomcat 7, and when I call a servlet via jQuery ajax, it gives me the following error:

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Here is the ajax code:

```
   $.get("ServletName", { label: data1value
                }, function(responseText){

                    alert('response Text: ' + responseText);


                    });

                });
```

Where am I going wrong? Kindly assist me.

Comment: Maybe it could help if you also show which libraries you used and the versions server-side. Since you don't have the problems with apache 8 I think the problem is on the server side.

Comment: I am using gson-2.3.1 library and other one Agena API